# eclipse: Ant property not accessable when running in separate JRE

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have setup an Ant runtime property in Preferences -> Ant -> Runtime -> Properties. It is named build.tools and has value ${workspace_loc:/ivd-build}

I have a build.xml with the following

```
<project name="myProject">
    <target name="test">
        <echo>"${build.tools}"</echo>
    </target>   
</project>
```

If I choose "Run in same JRE as workspace" I get (1)

```
[echo] "C:\Users\myuser\ws\seqflow-ivd\trunk\ivd-build"
```

If I choose "Separate JRE" I get (2)

```
[echo] "${workspace_loc:/ivd-build}"
```

So in the latter case the property is not resolved properly.

I would prefer the behavior of (1) but running in a separate JRE and I get this behavior on another machine. So I think it is some kind of setting somewhere, I just cannot find it.

Any suggestions?

- Windows 7
- Issue both seen with eclipse mars and neon.
- Java 1.8u66

Comment: I now have a mars and neon eclipse on the same machine, both with the Ant job configured as "Separate JRE". Mars can resolve the property, neon cannot. But I have another machine where a mars installation cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the problem.

Besides the `build.tools` property I also have another property (`other.tools`) which is rarely used. The cases where build.tools could not be resolved was caused by the fact that `other.tools` could not be resolved. When I corrected or removed `other.tools`, then `build.tools` resolved correctly (as (1)).

This means that if you want to use the "Separate JRE" setting for your Ant job, you need to ensure that all properties can be resolved even if you do not use them from your Ant script.